# How to count from an entire different google sheet for only one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, counting, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I am counting the number of projects/rows from a different google sheet using a specific criterion. The total count will show in one cell only.

`=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=359656787","HIP Campaign!H:H"),"Regular Campaign(Jan7-Feb21)")`

HIP Campaign is the sheet name from the different google sheet link. H:H range is where you can find value like Regular Campaign(Jan7-Feb21). I need to count the number of rows which has the value of Regular Campaign in range H:H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to link sheets by allowing access. run anywhere this formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "HIP Campaign!H1")
```

when linked you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(IFERROR(
 IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "HIP Campaign!H:H")), 
 "Regular Campaign(Jan7-Feb21)")
```